# Connecting a database to visual basic through code

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

i used this function to create a database:

```
Public Function CreateAccessDatabase (ByVal DatabaseFullPath As String) As Boolean        


        Dim bAns As Boolean
        Dim cat As New ADOX.Catalog()
        Try
            Dim sCreateString As String
            sCreateString = _
              "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & _
               DatabaseFullPath
            cat.Create(sCreateString)

            bAns = True

        Catch Excep As System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
            bAns = False
        Finally
            cat = Nothing
        End Try
        Return bAns
 End Function
```

and i want to connect it through code, i tried this but it doesnt work:

```
Try

        Dim constring As String
        constring = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Utilizador.Utilizador-PC\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\Doc_Vendas_Cab.mdf;"
        Dim conn As New SqlConnection(constring)
        conn.Open()
        MsgBox("Connected")

        conn.Close()
    Catch Ex As Exception
        MsgBox(Ex)
    End Try
```

how should i do it?

Comment: Are you getting any kind of error?

Comment: "but it doesnt work:" - please explain...

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in the *More Information* section from the page you copied the code from [here](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=5797)?

Comment: And it doesn't help you're using `SqlConnection` when you should be using `OleDbConnection`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using ms-access database in you code why are you using **SqlConnection** provider it is for SQL server database. 
You have to use **`OleDb.OleDbConnection`** provider.

See, this example link is **[helpful](http://p2p.wrox.com/access/86732-vbulletin-net-ms-access-connection.html)**

```
Try

    Dim constring As String
    constring = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Utilizador.Utilizador-PC\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\Doc_Vendas_Cab.mdf;"
    Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(constring)
    conn.Open()
    MsgBox("Connected")
    conn.Close()
Catch Ex As Exception
    MsgBox(Ex)
End Try
```